# Cannot use Microdia Webcam Vitade AF in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: usb, webcam, camera

I have bought an usb camera (0c45:6366 Microdia Webcam Vitade AF) and it does not work with ubuntu 22.04 in my desktop. It does not work with cheese or any other program.

Some commands I tried looking into possible solutions that might help you help me is:

```
sudo dmesg | grep -i "Camera"
[123172.525829] usb 1-1.6.2: Product: USB 2.0 Camera
[123172.799300] usb 1-1.6.2: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (0c45:6366)
```

```
sudo ls -ltrh /dev/video*
ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory
```

```
sudo v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.
```

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0c45:6366 Microdia Webcam Vitade AF
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0a05:7211 Unknown Manufacturer hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0a05:7211 Unknown Manufacturer hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1bcf:0c31 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. SPIF30x Serial-ATA bridge
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
locate v4l1compat.so
/snap/gimp/393/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so
/snap/gnome-42-2204/65/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so
/snap/gnome-42-2204/68/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so
```

```
sudo dmesg | tail -20
[126969.755340] usb 1-1.6.2: USB disconnect, device number 10
[126972.668346] usb 1-1.6.2: new full-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[126973.064715] usb 1-1.6.2: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[126973.076566] usb 1-1.6.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0c45, idProduct=6366, bcdDevice= 1.00
[126973.076575] usb 1-1.6.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=3
[126973.076578] usb 1-1.6.2: Product: USB 2.0 Camera
[126973.076581] usb 1-1.6.2: Manufacturer: Sonix Technology Co., Ltd.
[126973.076583] usb 1-1.6.2: SerialNumber: SN0001
[126973.246042] usb 1-1.6.2: 2:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
[126973.297893] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[126973.318671] usb 1-1.6.2: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (0c45:6366)
[126973.318678] usb 1-1.6.2: No valid video chain found.
[126973.318718] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[126973.525307] usb 1-1.6.2: 2:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
[126973.712870] usb 1-1.6.2: 2:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye not yet, my friend. Trying again today.